# Неадекватное поведение редактора в панели разработчика Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, инструменты-разработчика, импорт

Я правлю файлы css в панели разработчика. Очень наглядно, можно переходить в редактор по ссылке на строку, сохранение есть... Мне как новичку очень нравится
Но недавно я добавил в один файл такую строчку: `@import "/css/scroll-button.css";`, и началась жуть. Через один-пять набранных символов происходит будто обновление страницы в редакторе: вкладка данного файла пропадает на долю секунды, может пропасть один-два последних символа, исчезает метка несохранённых изменений, собственно и быстрое сохранение после этого не работает. Удалил строку - всё успокоилось.
Я что, неправильно импорт сделал? Заходил в импортированный файл - тот нормально себя ведёт.